# Como chamar Rules com FluentValidation a partir do retorno booleano de outra Rule

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, fluentvalidation

Tenho várias Rules de validação, porém criei uma nova que retorna um booleano, e se essa Rule for true, quero que não passe pelas outras validações, se for false, quero que passe pelas outras validações.

```
    public InternalInpectionMandatorinessValidator()
    {
        InspectionResult = new InspectionResultHolder();

            // Essas são as regras que devem ou não serem executadas a partir da outra Rule
            RuleFor(i => i)
                .RuleForZurichRenewal(InspectionResult)
                .RuleForBranchRenewal(InspectionResult)
                .RuleForNewInsurance(InspectionResult)
                .RuleForRcvPackage(InspectionResult)
                .RuleForBrandNew(InspectionResult)
                .WithName("Inspection");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você pode tentar utilizar os [RuleSets](https://jeremyskinner.co.uk/2011/02/03/fluentvalidation-v3-rulesets/)